# Import Paradox table in Access database: Incorrect collating sequence

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, paradox

I have a Paradox 5.0 database and want to migrate it to Access 2007. But if I try to import a Paradox table, Access gives an error message: "Incorrect collating sequence". The Help says: "You tried to link a Paradox table that was created with an international sort order that is not the same as the one you are using".

What am I doing wrong? How can I change that sort order?

Anybody? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem in Access 2000.

Nobody?

Comment: I haven't worked with Paradox files for a very long time, but I always found it easier to change the PDOX collation to something else, rather than changing it in my target Access file and then changing it back. But I last had Paradox data in PDOX 4.x for DOS! I haven't used Paradox since 1995 or so.

Comment: I've tried almost everything (Sort order Paradox, Registry settings) but it keeps saying "Incorrect collating sequence". It drives me crazy!

Comment: You say you've tried everything, but have you opened the file in Paradox and changed the collation in Paradox? If not, you haven't tried what I recommended. Another thing to try would be to export from Paradox to some intermediate format and then import into Access.

Comment: I've changed the sort order in the Paradox table (Table > Sort in the menu) if that is what you mean (I'm Dutch).
Yes, an intermediate format: I'am now exporting the Paradox data to comma-separated files and then import them in Access, it works.

Comment: I don't know the terminology in the Windows versions of Paradox. Back in the DOS days, you had to delete the indexes change the collation sequence (I don't recall how that was done) and then add the indexes back with the new collation. Sorry I can't be of more assistance on that. The intermediate format seems like a much easier task!